# Fake position Fixed inside a Div but relative to window top, while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed, scrolltop

I had to fake a fixed position of a div inside its container but relative to window by giving it an absolute position and giving it the top value in with jquery's scrollTop(). So far it seems like a decent solution but the fixed effect only work in Chrome. In firefox and ie10 it moves slowly and ie9 it do something like vibrate

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //First I had to do some hack in order to get the scrollTop() same return in all browsers
var bodyPos = $('body').scrollTop();
}else{

    var bodyPos = $('html,  body').scrollTop();
    }

//then I can calculate the point relative to the top of the window

var pos1 = $('#four').position().top;

var imgPos = bodyPos - pos1

$('#fixed1').css({'top': imgPos})
```

Anybody knows how to make this effect crossbrowser?

Thanks

Comment: are you debouncing your scroll handler?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - have a look at [Tether](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether)

Comment: @Bojangles I tried man, but it didn't work out, lol. Tether does just what I need, you're right. I just don't wanted to load more scripts. But I'm kindly short of time so I'll use it, thanks.

Comment: @StephenThomas thanks for the advice, that's probably what I should have done, I'll try it thought for next projects, it will de a good lesson.

Comment: @Bojangles I can't make it work, in this case what element would you choose as target, container, previous div?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed, as you see in this case I wanted to make a fake fixed position of an image inside it's container while scrolling.

Well, Occam's Razor:

I created a container for the image and give it an absolute position width height 100% and top  0. 
Then I set the image as background of the container with fixed attachment "et voilà" the job is done.

Sometimes this kind of things happen :)